# jQuery Mobile Taphold

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying the whole day to test a dead simple function in my project. The recipe is

1. The user taps and hold a list item
2. An `alert()` shows up.

My Markup is

```
...
<body>
   <ul>
      <li class="item ...">Hello, I'm an item</li>
      ...
   </ul>
</body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.mobile.js"></script>
...
```

My Script is

```
$('.item').on("taphold", function() {
   alert("hello");
});
```

I'm testing on an iPad 2 with Safari... My worry is, that jQuery mobile is deprecated, because the `click()` event works great. I've included the source from `http//jquerymobile.com`, this also didn't work.

Thank you!

Comment: replace `.live` with `.on` and you're not closing both functions `);`. Why are you placing js libraries after `<body>`? place them in `<head>`.

Comment: Done with that. Didn't work either.
Oops, in my code it is closed, I will edit that here.

Comment: ok, now remove `pageinit` binding.

Comment: Look at my edit (the script section). Also not not working.
And: JQuery mobile says "Loading" although the DOM and page is fully loaded.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/7cf2t/ its working. have you moved jQ and jQM to `head`?

Comment: I think that the problem is that the elements with `.item` class do not exist when your script is loaded. Put the script at the end of your page or attach the event handler on the `document` element using $(document).on('taphold', 'li.item', function(){. Check my example.

Comment: Always keep js libraries in head (jQ and jQM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the elements with `.item` class do not exist in DOM at the time your script is loaded. Put the script at the end of your page or attach the event handler on the `document` element using `$(document).on('taphold', 'li.item', function(){`

I've created the below working examples.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
     <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Taphold event demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tap-page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Long-press (taphold) a list item</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                  <li class="item">Hello, I'm an item</li>
                  <li class="item">Hello, I'm another item</li>
               </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('li.item').bind( 'taphold', tapholdHandler );

                function tapholdHandler( event ){
                  alert('Hello');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and an example which attaches an event handler on the `document` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Taphold event demo</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on( 'taphold', 'li.item', tapholdHandler );

            function tapholdHandler( event ){
              alert('Hello');
            }       
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tap-page" data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                 <h1>Long-press (taphold) a list item</h1>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                  <li class="item">Hello, I'm an item</li>
                  <li class="item">Hello, I'm another item</li>
               </ul>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. I will mark that as accepted.
You guys (Tolis, Omar) are awesome, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Omar I think that `.bind` is not deprecated in any way. Could you point me an official reference which says that it is deprecated? The doc just says that the preferred way is using `.on()`. In order to verify that it is not deprecated check the http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/ which does not contains the `.bind`. At last check the source code of the official jQM example regarding `taphold` event (v1.3.1) http://api.jquerymobile.com/resources/taphold/example1.html

Comment: I know, I went through it. Its preferred to follow latest updates, better for both you and OP.