# Jquery Taphold not working on dragdealerjs slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dragdealer-js

I am adding a series of divs with dragdealerjs functionality. The problem is I need to be able to tap and hold the ".handle" div inorder to expose a slider/drawer below it. I have simplified my code down to get to the root of the problem. I am appending the ".innerGroup" div to the ".groups" div.

HTML:

```
<div class="groups scroll">
    <div class="innerGroup">
        <div id="demo-simple-slider1" class="dragdealer">
            <div class="igIcon1"></div>
            <div class="handle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

This code doesn't work,

```
$(document).on('taphold', '.handle', function() {
 alert('Tapped');
});
```

This code does work though,

```
$(document).on('click', '.handle', function() {
 alert('Tapped');
});
```

I know there are several other similar answers to this one here but I fear that drag dealer may be complicating the issue. I also think the problem is related to adding the innerGroup after the DOM has loaded. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought the answers here would help, but they did not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252127/jquery-mobile-taphold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is that drag dealer actually takes control of the taphold event. To work around  you need to take a two stage check with a 750 millisecond time out (same as a standard taphold) and put the distance the slider can move as .49-.51 (or something similar ). If anyone wants the code leave a comment here and ill post what I come up with.

Happy coding